# Advanced content in grid tiles in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, meteor, grid-layout

I am about to make a dashboard with tiles.

In Meteor, I have a collection `Tiles`. My problem is that each tile should have different content.

I append the tiles to my template with

```
Template.grid.helpers({
  tiles: function() {
    return GridTiles.find();
  }
});
```

and print the tiles in my template with

```
{{#each tiles}}
  {{> gridItem}}
{{/each}}
```

so I can easily make a field `content` in my collection `Tiles` and print this content in each `gridItem`; however, my content should be fairly more complex.

One tile has some (auto)form inputs, another tile has a table with data (coming from another collection), etc.

I am confident that I should have a template for each of the different types of content, e.g.

```
<template name="gridType1">
  <form ...
  </form>
</template>

<template name="gridType2">
  <table ...
  </table>
</template>
```

but how can I choose which template should be in which tile? I could save the template name in my `Tiles` collection. But is this the smartest? And how can I include a template from a name obtained in the collection?

## Edit

I guess I will do it with something like this

```
<template name="gridItem">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="grid-item-content">
        <a href="#" class="remove-tile">x</a>
        {{#if templateName}}
          {{> Template.dynamic template=templateName }}
        {{else}}
          <p>Change tile type</p>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">table</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">form inputs</a></li>
          </ul>
        {{/if}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Does it make sense?

Comment: how do you work out what template to render?

Comment: I haven't figured out yet. Do you have any comments on how to do it? I guess it will be a dropdown where the user can choose which type of tile to create. Or maybe it should just create an empty tile with some options to change the "tile type", and thus rendering another template

Comment: well I'm not too sure,  but if your tiles collection is saying what "widgets" there are then it makes sense the tile knows the type of widget.   Then you can make a helper that translates the type to a template to render using a dynamic template like I outlined in my answer

Comment: I have made an edit to my question

Answer (score 0):

Meteor supports dynamic templates.

so

```
{{> Template.dynamic template=aHelperMethodThatWorksOutTheTemplateName [data=dataContextThatTheTemplateWillNeed] }}
```